# How to concatenating javascript variable in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using PHP and I have added below some script in the PHP.

```
$data.='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script>
        $(".nav-tabs button").click(function () {
        $("button").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");   
               
       var tabactive=$(this).attr("data-bs-target");
       $(".tab-content .tab-pane").removeClass("show active");
       var a=$(#"\"tabactive"\");
       alert(a); // testing purpose
       a.addClass("show active");
    });

</script>';
```

I am getting the issue in the below code.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: '#' not followed by identifier

```
 var a=$(#"\"tabactive"\");
```

How to concatenate javascript variable in jquery?

Comment: What JS syntax are you trying to generate? What JS syntax are you actually getting (view the source in the browser).

Comment: @Quentin, I am not generating any js. I just want to add the class to the tab-content when the user clicks on the tab.

Comment: @JustStarted — Really? So your question isn't about writing a PHP program which outputs some JS?!

Comment: @Quentin, There is a lot of PHP code so I haven't added it to the question. I am getting the target value but not able to concatenating.

Comment: I never suggested you should show us more PHP.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a javascript syntax issue. You need the `#` in quotes so it is read as a string. It should be concatenated to your JS variable like this:

```
var a=$("#" + tabactive );
```

or in the full PHP blob:

```
$data.='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script>
        $(".nav-tabs button").click(function () {
        $("button").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");   
               
       var tabactive=$(this).attr("data-bs-target");
       $(".tab-content .tab-pane").removeClass("show active");
       var a=$("#" + tabactive);
       alert(a); // testing purpose
       a.addClass("show active");
    });

</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate JavaScript variable to jQuery check the following code:

```
var word = "word";
var a = $("#" + word );
```

Is it that you searching for?